# Instance attributes are not available in metadata

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-logging

I'm setting up a new K8S Cluster (1.13.7-gke.8) on GKE and I want the Google cloud logging API to report properly namespace and instance names.

This is executed in a new GKE cluster with workload-identity enabled.

I started workload container to test the access to metadata service and these are the results:

```
kubectl run -it --generator=run-pod/v1 --image google/cloud-sdk --namespace prod --rm workload-identity-test
```

And from the container after executing:

```
curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

I expect the output of cluster-name, container-name, and namespace-id, but the actual output is only cluster-name.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same but when I ran the following the metadata showed up:

```
gcloud beta container node-pools create [NODEPOOL_NAME] \
  --cluster=[CLUSTER_NAME] \
  --workload-metadata-from-node=EXPOSED
```

However, you will only get `cluster-name` from the metadada. For example,

```
root@workload-identity-test:/# curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
cluster-location
cluster-name
cluster-uid
configure-sh
created-by
disable-legacy-endpoints
enable-oslogin
gci-ensure-gke-docker
gci-update-strategy
google-compute-enable-pcid
instance-template
kube-env
kube-labels
kubelet-config
user-data
```

If you are looking at getting namespaces and containers, I suggest you look at talking directly to the [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/) which essentially what the 'Workloads' tab on GKE does. I'm not really sure what you are trying to do with the 'Google cloud logging API' but maybe you can elaborate on a different question.

Comment: The google cloud logging api requires metadata attributes cluster-name, container-name and namespace-id to be able to structure properly logs in the console and as I understand should be populated automatically by the stackdriver agents which are using the Kubernetes API. I suspect that it is related to this issue https://github.com/Stackdriver/kubernetes-configs/issues/25 but I'm not able to find any logs.

Comment: --workload-metadata-from-node=EXPOSED is deprecated seems to be the right parameter GCE_METADATA